# Is there a easy way to handing 404 error in a JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I do not want every time using:

```
if(!new File(file).exists()){
    //createFile /doc/a.txt ...
}
request.getRequestDispatcher("/doc/a.txt").forward(request, response);
```

I would like to know how can i implement the following code:

```
try{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/doc/a.txt").forward(request, response);
}catch(404 error){
    //createFile /doc/a.txt ...
}
```

How can I handing 404 error just in this page?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best handled by an error section in your `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but I only need handing 404 error just in this page,not of all

Comment: Yes. This is a prefect solution. No need to handle the Exception in try catch. Just mention the error page name to be shown when application encounter http 404 error.

Comment: You're right @Reimeus,I feel this is a bit complicated,I'm looking for an easier way if possible

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't this work for you:

```
try{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/doc/a.txt").forward(request, response);
}catch(Exception error){
    //createFile /doc/a.txt ...
}
```